# PyQt: Running pyuic.py without command line

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, pyuic

I am unable to use the command prompt due to security restrictions on my work PC and I am trying unsuccessfully to find a way to convert .ui files to .py without the pyuic4 batch file.

I have found the uic/pyuic.py program but have been unsuccessful in my attempts to run it from a python console.

Any help with this would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: Use the [uic module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#the-uic-module).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks ekhumoro,

Was able to implement the uic successfully, using compileUiDir, since I have multiple .ui files. Final code was:

```
from PyQt4 import uic
folderToConvert = r'filePathGoesHere'
uic.compileUiDir(folderToConvert,recurse=False)
```

This is a .py file that I run or call/execute prior to running the main program. Very handy!